# Get list of item from QtableWidget

Tags: python, qtablewidget

I have a TableWidget with checkBoxes in it. I want to know if there is a way to get the checkBoxes(items) back to a List.
Later I want to check which checkBoxes are checked.
self.path is a List with paths.

```
def fill_table(self):
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.path))
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 275)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
    self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet('font: 12pt \"Arial\";')
    row = 0
    for file in self.path:
        checkBox = self.popluate_checkBox(str(file))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, checkBox)
        row = row + 1

def popluate_checkBox(self, name):
    checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
    checkBox.setText(str(name))
    return checkBox
```